# How Firebase defines current user in Auth?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase Auth with Google and doing everyrhing through Firebase docs, and in my `SigninActivity`, I have **onStart** method, which check is there are current user or no.

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        updateUI(currentUser);
    }
```

and also have

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
```

which signs out user.

And i cannot understand, how Firebase defines current user, when he not logged in yet.
Is there are unique ID for app or how ?

Comment: You got it totally wrong bud. If you haven't signed in a user before doing getUser in onStart, it'll give you NPE because user doesn't exist yet. So, for example, there js one method in FirebaseAuth which is something like signInUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password), which you call after getting user details from Login Screen, then the user is created in your firebase account, and also saved locally, maybe in SharedPreferences. Check if you're logging in the user someone using some other method.

Comment: @AlexMamo, Yes, And also i dont understand, how Firebase knows current user, when he not signed in yet ? I mean, which criteria Firebase checks in this method `FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();` How does Firebase identify individual user? Does each user have own Firebase ID or smth like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comments:

> Yes, And also i dont understand, how Firebase knows current user, when he not signed in yet ? I mean, which criteria Firebase checks in this method FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser()

Firebase "knows" when the current user is logged in or not by checking the [FirebaseUser](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser) object for nullity. If the user is logged in, when using the following line of code:

```
FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
```

It returns a non nullable `FirebaseUser` object. This is the reason why we always check it for nullity. If you are using the following line of code:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
```

It means that the `FirebaseUser` becomes `null`, which also means that the user has signed out.